# XPath of the edit button is //*[@id="edit_1088"]

Tags: ruby, xpath, cucumber, capybara

My query is I need to click on the first edit link on the table. The table has 7 columns and rows will be incremented dynamically.
HTML Code for first row:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
<td>
<form method="GET" target="_blank" action>...</form>
<td> ALLOCATION CHANGE</td>
<td class="right"></td>
<td> SATTER, KRAIG</td>
<td> CAFEMANAGER1</td>
<td class="sorting_1">03/08/2016 17:00</td>
<td class="edit_icon" id="edit_1088" onclick="on EditClick(1088)">
<span class="view_icon" style="margin-left: 40%;"></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Note: the ID of the edit button keep on changing as the row increments.

Mycode in cucumber -ruby -capybara

```
 And /^I click on the Expresso image$/ do
 find(:xpath, '//*[@id="l1row"]/span').click
 find('tr:odd > td:edit_icon [id="edit_"] match: first').click
 sleep 10
 end
```

Error Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read "[mcve]". We need the minimal input, plus an example of your code demonstrating the problem, along with the expected output. Also, it's not necessary to say "Please help", since that's what the site is for in the first place. You should also read "[ask]" and all the links at the bottom of the page as it'll help you ask a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update based on the posted HTML -

Note: Your first <td> isn't closed, I'm assuming thats just an error when you were adding the HTML to the question.

So from the HTML posted you don't actually have an edit link you just have a td you need to click on - the one in the first row with an id beginning with "edit_" so

```
find('tr:first-child > td[id^="edit_"]').click
```

The attempt you posted in your question won't work because there is no such CSS selector as `odd` or `edit_icon` and find needs valid CSS selectors (or XPath if you specify XPath or set it as your default)

Previous Answer Based on the wording of the question:

If this is a table then you can do what you want with CSS and not worry about XPath.

```
find('tr:first-child > td:last-child [id^="edit_"]')
```

will find the element whose `id` starts with "edit_" in the last td in the first row.  If your rows and columns are not actually a table you'll need to provide some example HTML of what you're talking about.

Comment: The OP needs to show more information; Guessing what they're trying to do is an exercise in frustration. Instead, request what you need so you can formulate the answer that definitely solves the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan That makes sense when there is no chance of guessing what the OP really meant - and that ends up meaning a roundtrip of days before things get answered.  Sometimes its easier to make assumptions (talking about rows and columns means its somewhat likely to be a table) and answer that.  The answer can always be removed if the OP clarifies that its not a table

Comment: You can also gather lots of downvotes quickly if the assumption is wrong. Since the idea is that we ask questions to improve the question to make it more useful for future users *along with* the OP, it benefits everyone to get clarification up front since it'll never happen after the fact.

Comment: @theTinMan So I get downvotes - doesn't really bother me.  If the assumption is correct it becomes obvious when the OP accepts the answer.  If not the OP will clarify and the answer can be deleted or downvoted. If the assumption is correct the question is answered more quickly.  If the assumption is incorrect no more time elapses than would have normally - I don't get the downside.

Comment: Sorry for not describing my problem completely.

Comment: Code i used:`require 'rubyXL'
require 'roo'
workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file_name)
workbook1 = RubyXL::Parser.parse(file_name)
workbook.default_sheet='AllocationChange'
worksheet1 = workbook1['AllocationChange']
choose("lookupSearch", :option => "Contract") 
fill_in "searchInput", :with => workbook.cell(1,1)
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="sidebar"]/div[2]/div/a[2]').click
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="edit_contains(0,9)%]"]').click
find(:xpath, '//*[@id="deleteDetails"]').click    `

Comment: yes it is a table with 7 columns. Rows are dynamic. So once i submit a value the row gets incremented and the submitted data is displayed in the first row. The last column(#7) has two icons edit and view. Now i need to click on the edit of the first row -last column. I'm writing in cucumber -ruby- capybara. `HTML``<td class="edit_icon" id="edit_1094" onclick="onEditClick(1094)"><span class="view_icon" style="margin-left: 30%;"></span></td>`

Comment: @RPD  If the solution I posted isn't working for you - edit your question above and add some example HTML so you can format it correctly

Comment: @ Tom Walpole Yes the solution is not working . I have edited the query by adding html code, my code and the error message. Please advice

Comment: @RPD the selector you show in your code is the not the one I had above so I'm not sure what you're showing - I've updated the answer to match the html you posted